# SAS SQL Join 3 tables but have duplication issues

Tags: sql, join, sas

I am joining three tables by PolicyNbr and asking back the base premiums from three different calculations made previous to this SQL statement. The specific PolicyNbr I am working with has two locations which means that we should have two of the same PolicyNbrs with two different loc numbers (1 and 2). When I join all three tables together I am getting 6 policies numbers vs. 2 (locations 1 and 2). This duplication is because I am not joining the tables together correctly. Could use some help.

```
Proc SQL;
create table FR_TOTAL_&thestate. as

select distinct
S1.PolicyNbr, S1.Loc, S1.SLoc,

S1.S1_BASEPREM, 

S3.S3BPP_BASEPREM, 

S4.S4_BaseRate

from FR_S12_&thestate. S1, FR_S3_&thestate. S3, FR_S4_&thestate. S4
where S1.PolicyNbr = S3.PolicyNbr 
and S3.PolicyNbr = S4.PolicyNbr 
and S1.PolicyNbr = S4.PolicyNbr 
and S1.PolicyNbr="40P803"
group by S1.PolicyNbr
order by S1.PolicyNbr;
Quit;
```

Comment: (1) We can't help you join your tables together without seeing their layout and preferably sample data; (2) You should tag your question with the appropriate database.  If you are using `proc sql` with no backend database, then "mysql" and "sql-server" are not appropriate.

Comment: I'd guess mysql...it's the only database that won't barf at his group by statement. And then I'm confused at why proc SQL would be in a mysql statement.  @user3934942 - you'll need to clarify for us if you want help.  What database are you on?  If you give some sample rows, it's easier to deduce where the duplicate is coming from when we can see the duplicates.

Comment: I am using SAS with a PROC SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Without data this is just an educated guess.

You are getting duplicates because you are implicitly doing a cross join (Cartesian product).  You probably need to add the location to the `WHERE` clause.

Best practice is to specify your join type (inner, left, etc.) as it forces you to know your data.

Read the chapter in the SAS doc for SQL on joining multiple tables (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/65065/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1r5d2j8962os6n1how8t5mj3ut5.htm).

The doc is a pretty good primer on SQL.

Comment: Also - if you are joining correctly you will not need to use the distinct keyword.  If you are using distinct to remove duplicates from a join, it just means you don't understand your data yet.  Don't do it.

Comment: I can think of a few isolated cases where you might, but it is something like "show me the distinct IP addresses people with the last name 'Pazzula' logged in.  That is not that case.